# Data export to Excel Using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to export data into Excel file from ole db source. The data type is money.
When I extract the data in Excel. I see an error in the cell "The number in the cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe." How can I get rid of this error when the file generates? When I loan the column, I have set it as currency[DT_CY] data type in ole db source and excel destination editor.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a *message* (not even a warning) telling you exactly that: that the cell contains text. The reason for this is that `money` is a problematic type. It has a fixed scale and implies the existence of a currency, without ever specifying that currency. That's why it's *not* used in databases. Whenever money is saved, a `numeric(p,s)` with an explicit scale is used, with the currency stored in a different field

Comment: Excel doesn't have a `money` type. You can specify the display format for a field from the cell's style properties but *you* have to specify the currency symbol to use. The only way SSIS can store money with a specific format (eg with a symbol) is to store it as text

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is related to how Excel treats the values from the OLE DB source (as text instead of numbers).

Ensure you correctly convert the data type to currency (DT_CY) in the Data Flow Task before writing it to the Excel destination. You can explicitly use the "Data Conversion" transformation in SSIS to convert the data type to DT_CY.

Add the "Data Conversion" transformation between the OLE DB Source and the Excel Destination in your Data Flow Task.
Configure the "Data Conversion" transformation to convert the money column to DT_CY data type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is already coming as currency(DT_CY) data type. But I still went ahead and added data conversion transformation and added the conversion as you suggested. I then mapped to new column. But it didnt work. IT populates data in the Excel with same error. I noticed when I right click Excel Destination Editor and click on Advanced editor, I saw that under External Columns, the data type is Unicode string [DT_WSTR] and on Input columns, the data type is DT_CY.

Comment: If I change Unicode string[DT_WSTR] to DT_CY, it resets itself to Unicode string[DT_WSTR] . Not sure why the data type is not changing to DT_CY after I change it in External columns.

Comment: Also I am using template excel file with prepopulated header columns

Comment: Can you update your question with all the information so we can understand better your problem ?

Comment: My controlflow tasks => Files system Task(Template with header columns) => DFT(OLE DB Source => Excel Destination).

My first task is File system Task where I am  using prepopulated header template excel file. Then the Data flow task will use that template to populate from OLE DB source to Excel Destination). One 
of the column(Revenue) is data type money in database. But when I export the data to Excel, that column data gets exported as text and not currency. So I get error in the excel cell "The number in this cell is formatted as 
formatted as text or by an apostrophe"

Comment: How can I export that Revenue column exported as currency? I even tried using data conversion transformation but its not working. I am guessing it has to do with using Excel Template file with prepopulated header. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. ​ I got the solution. I need to use Macros to convert text to numbers and use .xlsm instead of .xlsx in template file.